# How can use Azure Machine Learning notebooks to connect to SQL Server and Azure SQL databases?

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, azure-sql-database, azure-machine-learning-service

I'm trying to find out how I can use a Microsoft Azure Machine Learning notebook to connect to SQL Server and Azure SQL databases.

I am aware of how to connect to SQL Server databases with regular Jupyter files with the use of ODBC connections. But, it looks like I have to try something different when using Azure Machine Learning notebooks.

Could someone describe the best approach to accomplish this?

Note: I am referring to the new Microsoft Azure Machine Learning service, which is currently in preview mode as of May 2020.

Answer (score 3):

great question -- the answer depends on whether or not your data sources are in Azure.

### data in Azure

for Azure based storage (blob, data lake, Azure SQL, Azure Databricks) you're in luck with Azure ML `Datasets`, and abstraction on top of `azureml-dataprep`, a component package of `azureml-sdk`. IMHO, Azure ML `Datasets` are slick, [`TabularDatasets`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.data.tabulardataset?view=azure-ml-py) in particular with their `to_pandas_dataframe()` and `.to_spark_dataframe()` methods.

Check out the following articles for guidance on how to:

- [How to connect to data and register as a `Dataset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-access-data)
- [How to access data during training](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-train-with-datasets)
  Follow the recommendations in this tutorial recommendation would be to make a `TabularDataset` FileDataset

### data not in Azure

For on-premise or IaaS SQL servers, you've got two options that I'm aware of:

- Put your SQL server inside the same network at the Azure ML service and ComputeTarget and access the server directly with `pyodbc` library.
- [Use ADF to move the SQL server data to Azure Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-data-ingest-adf), (you'll need an ADF integration runtime on the SQL server)

Comment: no reference to Azure SQL in your Dataset link